# Spark - load string containing special characters into a Spark dataframe

Tags: python, json, dataframe, apache-spark, utf-8

I have following situation here - I am fetching results from API using urllib.request library:

```
response = compatible_urllib.urlopen(request).read()
```

and as a response I am getting following stringified JSON:

```
    response = '{"result":[{"kanalID":1,"kanal":"TV","kanalLongName":"TV","kanalNumber":"XTV1","thumbnail":"empty","externalID":1,"lastUpdate":"none"},{"kanalID":2,"kanal":"Mre\u017ea","kanalLongName":"Mre\u017ea","kanalNumber":"XTV2","thumbnail":"empty","externalID":2,"lastUpdate":"none"}]}'
```

Problem is in part of string 'Mre\u017ea' which in the end should be displayed in database like - Mreža, because \u017e is representation of character ž.

I am processing results from API using Spark dataframes and when I do it in following way:

```
channels_json = ast.literal_eval(response)
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([channels_json ]), schema=schema_struct)
```

As a df I am getting results in dataframe and further in database (Hive), but \u017e is displayed as a \\u017e.

I was suggested to use json.loads instead of literal_eval, but when I use it like this:

```
    channels_json_b = json.loads(response)
```

value of channels_json_b is:

```
{u'result': [{u'lastUpdate': u'none', u'kanal': u'TV', u'kanalID': 1, u'kanalLongName': u'TV', u'externalID': 1, u'kanalNumber': u'XTV1', u'thumbnail': u'empty'}, {u'lastUpdate': u'none', u'kanal': u'Mre\u017ea', u'kanalID': 2, u'kanalLongName': u'Mre\u017ea', u'externalID': 2, u'kanalNumber': u'XTV100001608', u'thumbnail': u'empty'}]}
```

But if I try to load this JSON (channels_json_b) into a dataframe I am getting empty dataframe:

```
df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize([channels_json_b]), schema=schema_struct)
```

Did I need to do something else before trying to load this JSON info a dataframe?
I guess problem is not in schema I am using because it works fine when literal_eval is used instead of json.loads

Comment: I managed to solve this with literal_eval method, just by adding this line         response = json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')
Problem were caused by prints across my code which cause errors in code and directed me in wrong direction in detecting solution.